# smoothly slide up or down when sizes change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made two button `.square` related to two `<div>`.
If I click on one button `.square` : a related `<div>` appear, and the other disapear.
Thing is :
The content I display right after (`bellow_div`) 
is making a strange transition when the height of `#c1` or `#c2` are changing.
How to smoothly slide up or down `bellow_div` and `#c1` or `#c2` when changing height ?

```js
$(function(){ // DOM ready shorthand
$('.square:first').css('color', 'red');
                 
$(".square").on("click", function() { 
 
    var id= $(this).attr("contentId");
        $('.square').css('color', ' #ccc');
    $(this).css('color','red');

    $('#details p').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).html($("#" + id).html()).fadeIn();
    });


});



});
```

```css
#details{
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square" contentId="c1">Prochain évenement</div>
<div class="square" contentId="c2">Editorial</div>

<div id="details">
<p>
Jeudi 20 Mars<br>
20h30<br>
                                    
Upcoming eventsSed si ille hac tam eximia fortuna propter utilitatem rei publicae frui non properat, ut omnia illa conficiat, quid ego, senator, facere debeo, quem, etiamsi ille aliud vellet, rei publicae consulere oporteret?
</p></div>

<div style="display: none" id="c1">

Jeudi 20 Mars<br>
20h30<br>                           
Upcoming eventsSed si ille hac tam eximia fortuna propter utilitatem rei publicae frui non properat, ut omnia illa conficiat, quid ego, senator, facere debeo, quem, etiamsi ille aliud vellet, rei publicae consulere oporteret?
</div>

<div style="display: none" id="c2">
Saison 2016—2017

</div>

<div class="bellow_div">Here is a text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` jQuery functions.

```js
$(function(){ // DOM ready shorthand
$('.square:first').css('color', 'red');
                 
$(".square").on("click", function() { 
 
    var id= $(this).attr("contentId");
        $('.square').css('color', ' #ccc');
    $(this).css('color','red');

    $('#details p').slideUp().fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).html($("#" + id).html()).slideDown().fadeIn();
    });


});



});
```

```css
#details{
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square" contentId="c1">Prochain évenement</div>
<div class="square" contentId="c2">Editorial</div>

<div id="details">
<p>
Jeudi 20 Mars<br>
20h30<br>
                                    
Upcoming eventsSed si ille hac tam eximia fortuna propter utilitatem rei publicae frui non properat, ut omnia illa conficiat, quid ego, senator, facere debeo, quem, etiamsi ille aliud vellet, rei publicae consulere oporteret?
</p></div>

<div style="display: none" id="c1">

Jeudi 20 Mars<br>
20h30<br>                           
Upcoming eventsSed si ille hac tam eximia fortuna propter utilitatem rei publicae frui non properat, ut omnia illa conficiat, quid ego, senator, facere debeo, quem, etiamsi ille aliud vellet, rei publicae consulere oporteret?
</div>

<div style="display: none" id="c2">
Saison 2016—2017

</div>

<div class="bellow_div">Here is a text</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Wowsk, thank you for the help. The effect is almost good, isn't there a way to avoid closing entirely the gray div, and just slide till the next div appear ?

Comment: In terms of scenario, it would be : 1 - fadeOut text ; 2 - slide till the next div height ; 3 - fadeIn next text

Answer (score 0):

Check `the Executing Code When an Animation Ends` section [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end)